# How to install titan 1.0.0 api for java

Tags: java, api, groovy, titan, gremlin

I'm able to run groovy scripts via the gremlin console, but I wish to use titan db in Java files and I can't find a way to install Titan API for java.

Answer (score 3):

There is an example of a maven project using Titan here:

https://github.com/pluradj/titan-tp3-java-example